# How to clone/copy a sql record with CakePhp, and then grab the ID of the clone?

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

I have cloned/saved a copy of an SQL record using CakePhp like so:

```
$contract = $this->Contract->findById($id);
$contract['Contract']['id'] = NULL;
$this->Contract->save($contract); // And save it
```

I want to be able to redirect the user to the 'Edit' view of the cloned record after the clone is complete. Basically, I need to do something like this:

```
 $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'contracts', 'action' => 'edit', $cloneId));
```

My question is, how do I get the ID of the clone immediately after saving the new record?

Answer (score 3):

you can also get the last inserted record id in these ways.

```
$cloneId = $this->Contract->id;
```

or

```
$cloneId  = $this->Contract->getLastInsertID();
```

or

```
$contract = $this->Contract->save($contract);
$cloneId = $contract['Contract']['id']
```